# Date Month Localization

Tags: java, android, date, localization, simpledateformat

I've this:

```
2015-09-18 12:24:16
```

And I need this:

```
18 settembre (localized month string)
```

I've tried this way:

```
private String formatDate(String dateString) {
        String formattedDate = "";
        Date date;
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf =
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            sdf.applyPattern("dd MMMM");
            formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedDate;
    }
```

Any pitfall with this code? Can it be simplified? Locale.getDefault will always get the right translation? Why applyPattern doc says:

"Changes the pattern of this simple date format to the specified pattern which **uses non-localized pattern** characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d1 = parser.parse("2015-09-18 12:24:16");
SimpleDateFormat parser1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM",new Locale ("it"));
System.out.println(parser1.format(d1));
```

**Output:**

```
 18 settembre
```

Comment: I can't use an hardcoded Locale, I should get it from the "OS" somehow.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat parser1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM",new Locale ("it")); ` instead that , Use this : `SimpleDateFormat parser1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", (
    Locale.getDefault()));`

Answer (score 0):

for default locale use this : locale.getDefault().

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d1 = null;
        try {
            d1 = parser.parse("2015-09-18 12:24:16");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat parser1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM",Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(parser1.format(d1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currDate = Util.getCurrentDate();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see two major issues.

- **Outmoded classes**
  The old .Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.
- **Time zone**
  Date varies depending on what time zone you are in.

## Avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar

Avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The are notoriously confusing, troublesome, and flawed. Instead, use the successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. In Java 8 and later use the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework, inspired by Joda-Time.

## Time Zone

If precision matters, apply time zones. The date varies by where you are on the globe. For example, a new day rises earlier in Paris than in Montréal.

Ideally your input string would include either offset-from-UTC and/or time zone. If not, you must know the zone. Tell the parser the zone to use.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
```

## ISO 8601

Your string is nearly in standard format according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Those standard formats are used by default in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). So no need to define a format pattern if we replace the space in middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2015-09-18 12:24:16";
String inputStandard = input.replace( " " , "T" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( inputStandard , zone );
```

To get our desired String output, specify a `Locale` for the desired human language.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
```

If you want the JVM’s current default [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), I suggest you call for it to make your code self-documenting and explicit.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

But remember that the current default can change at any moment with a call to [`setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-) by any code in any thread in any app in your JVM. I suggest specifying a `Locale` rather than rely on default.

Define a [formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) by [specifying a pattern](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). Tell the formatter to use a specific `Locale` rather than your [JVM's current default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d MMMM" );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input + " in zone: " + zone + " is: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "In locale: " + locale + " = " + output );
```

When run.

```
input: 2015-09-18 12:24:16 in zone: America/Toronto is: 2015-09-18T12:24:16.000-04:00
In locale: fr_CA = 18 septembre
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).